# Android Vibration APIs

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, vibration

I am experimenting with sound manager application to create different sound profiles for "RING, NOTIFICATION, MEDIA, SYSTEM".

As per setting the volume level, I am succeeded with it by using

```
AudioManager setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, <value>);
```

The challenge comes with Vibration Settings.

Currently the api call:

```
AudioManager setVibrateSetting(vibrateType, vibrateSetting);
```

Is deprecated in API level 16 and no hope to use it..

The other alternatives is to use

```
AudioManager setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```

But I am precisely looking to turn off and turn on vibration for

- RINGER
- NOTIFICATIONS

from my custom application. Or turn on for one of them at any time.

You can think I am doing something similar to the enabling and disabling vibration in sound settings from the OS settings option.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
```

Answer (score -1):

For your concern firstly you need to define in Manifest file like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

And use like this in your class file. Wonder where exactly you need to put this.

```
// You need to define some sort of pattern for this
    Vibrator vb = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    long[] pattern = {0, 1000, 0};
    //long[] pattern = {startTime, TotalTimeDuration, not vibrating for 0ms}; .. Example for above stuff
    vb.vibrate(pattern, 0);
```

For Example:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    Vibrator vb = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                long[] pattern = {0, 1000, 0};
                vb.vibrate(pattern, 0);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                vb.cancel();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is just playing the vibration. What i needed is to turn on and turn on system vibration from my app. vibrate() is playing and cancel() is stopping the vibration which is playing. It has no impact on the vibration settings of the system.